# R - dplyr joining two df with conditions for rows (char)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am still a beginner with stackoverflow and dplyr. Perhaps that's why I couldn't find any other similar question.

Problem:
I have two df.

df1 contains a variable ("a") whose entries I want to compare with the entries of a variable in df2 ("c"). Both variables are characters.

If I have a match between both dfs I want to add a row in a new column ("new") which contains the string of df1 ("birne" etc.).

However, the length of each entrie differs between both variables. So perhaps a str_detect, or ends_with should be helpful.

```
##DFs
df1 <-data.frame("a"= c("055","022","010","0105","0777","077"), "b"= c("birne", "apfel", "banane","traube","blaubeere","kiwi"))

df2 <-data.frame("c"= c("GX00000055","GX0000022","GX00000010","GX00000105","GX0000777","GX0000077"))

## I want

df2_newcolumn<-data.frame("c"= c("GX00000055","GX0000022","GX00000010","GX00000105","GX0000777","GX0000077"), "new"=c("birne", "apfel","NA","NA","blaubeere","NA"))
```

I thought I can get it using left_join and filter in combination with ends_with, grepl or str_detect. However, I struggeld getting the correct combination and order of command.

Comment: If @Wimpel's answer does not resolve your question, I think you need to (a) fix your data to be consistent, and/or (b) explain how those `NA` are determined.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your desired output (what are there NA's in there?), but a regex join might be what you need:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)
df2 %>%
  regex_left_join(df1 %>% mutate(regex = paste0(a, "$")), by = c(c = "regex")) %>%
#            c    a         b regex
# 1 GX00000055  055     birne  055$
# 2  GX0000022  022     apfel  022$
# 3 GX00000010  010    banane  010$
# 4 GX00000105 0105    traube 0105$
# 5  GX0000777 0777 blaubeere 0777$
# 6  GX0000077  077      kiwi  077$
  select(c,b)
#            c         b
# 1 GX00000055     birne
# 2  GX0000022     apfel
# 3 GX00000010    banane
# 4 GX00000105    traube
# 5  GX0000777 blaubeere
# 6  GX0000077      kiwi
```

Comment: Thank you @Wimpel! Your suggestion sounds good. I tried to find more on regex_left_join because I was not yet able to transfer your solution to my real data. I will have to do some more research here to understand what is not working. And on that note, I can hopefully provide a new example of data soon. Thanks for your patience. I would be thankful if you can help me then again. BR